# How to generate 10x10km grid cells of all countries?

Tags: r, grid, gis, geospatial, r-sf

Good morning,

I am currently trying to get 10x10 (or 5x5) km grid cells of countries (no ocean) clipped to the borders. See for example a grid raster for Nigeria: [Nigeria Grid Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWx35.png)

**PLAN A:** My plan was to take the GADM level 0 map (https://gadm.org/data.html) with country borders and create grid cells accordingly.

While the st-grid command is easy, it takes ages to calculate (>30h for Nigeria)

```
 regions <- st_read("data/region/gadm36_0.shp") %>%
 st_transform("+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") 
 
grid<- st_make_grid(regions %>%
                           st_union(), cellsize = c(10000, 10000), square = T)
```

Even with a R Studio Pro sever it is taking a lot of time...

*Any idea to fasten this up?*

**PLAN B:** My second plan was to use the 10x10km grid raster from https://figshare.com/articles/Global_10_x_10-km_grids_suitable_for_use_in_IUCN_Red_List_of_Ecosystems_assessments_vector_and_raster_format_/4653439
and clip it to the GADM country shape file.

The problem is that I was not able to load the raster data file into R and to make it run with the crop and mask command from the sf package. *Does anybody have an idea how to make this run?*

**PLAN C:** Is there a 10x10km grid raster file for countries that already exsists? I am aware of the 50x50 grid by PRIO but didn´t find a good solution.

*Thanks a lot and hopefully you can help me solving this issue!*

Comment: I would love to post the picture directly but I don´t have the reputation :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring to **PLAN A**, instead of `sf::st_make_grid` you can create a raster with `stars::st_as_stars` and then transform it to polygons with `sf::st_as_sf`, which takes 1-2 seconds for Nigeria:

```r
library(sf)
library(stars)
library(rnaturalearth)

# Polygon
world = ne_countries(scale = "small", returnclass = "sf")
world = st_transform(world, "+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
pol = world[world$sovereignt == "Nigeria", ]

# Make grid
grid = st_as_stars(st_bbox(pol), dx = 10000, dy = 10000)
grid = st_as_sf(grid)
grid = grid[pol, ]

# Plot
plot(st_geometry(grid), axes = TRUE, reset = FALSE)
plot(st_geometry(world), border = "grey", add = TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(pol), border = "red", add = TRUE)
```

[image: grid]

Referring to **PLAN B**, the 10-km raster can be imported into R and cropped also using package `stars`, as follows:

```r
library(sf)
library(stars)
library(rnaturalearth)

# Raster
r = read_stars("AOOGrid_10x10kmRast/AOOGrid_10x10km.img")

# Polygon
world = ne_countries(scale = "small", returnclass = "sf")
world = st_transform(world, st_crs(r))
pol = world[world$sovereignt == "Nigeria", ]

# Crop
r = r[pol]

# Plot
plot(r, axes = TRUE, reset = FALSE)
plot(st_geometry(world), border = "grey", add = TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(pol), add = TRUE)
```

[image: raster]

Comment: Wow, @Michael Dorman, this is awesome! Thanks a lot for both answers! I slightly prefer option A but both run pretty smoothly. Speaking of saving time in GIS calculations: Option A produced a shp file of >200mb. I want to calculate the population for each cell by choosing the hyde data (in asc or tiff format) and it takes - again - really long because there are so many cells. Do you have an idea whether there is an easier way to match information from my shp file with the raster data if have for population? Shall I open another thread to explain it a bit more?

Comment: Hi @Luca, glad to hear it helped! I'm not sure I understand - you have another data source with population size data, and you need to "transfer" those values into the new grid? If so, then you may look into https://github.com/isciences/exactextractr using the "sum" option (if the population data are in a raster), or `sf::st_interpolate_aw` (if the population data are in a polygonal layer).

Comment: Dear @Michael Dorman, indeed I have another data source. I provided my quastion and code for the extractfunction here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574446/extracting-data-from-raster-file-to-match-with-shp-file

I think it is not the extract function (works with other shapefiles) but rather the shp that I produced in Option A.

Comment: Follow Up, @Michael: While there seems to be a problem with the projection by option A, option B works fine with the extract function! Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: As @robert-hijmans commented, it's difficult to tell what the problem is without a small (or at least a reproducible) example. You can try to narrow down exactly which raster and polygon layer raise the error, then post the specific code along with the layers in your question.

Comment: Ok, sure! I edited the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574446/extracting-data-from-raster-file-to-match-with-shp-file

Comment: Follow up question: Clipping Grid Cells to Borders

@Michael Dorman´s answer (option A) worked great for me. I am sure there is an easy solution to my follow up question, which I am struggling with currently:

As you can see below, the raster grid cells are overlapping with the borders.

Overlapping grid rasters

How can I crop/clip the rasters to borders as such that there is no overlap with other countries?

Thank you!